# Crear reproductor 360 para Android en Unity con Easy Movie Texture

Tags: android, unity3d, vr

Gente, buenas tardes!
Estoy necesitando hacer un reproductor de video 360 para Android, utilizando Unity, el típico de la cámara dentro de una esfera que reproduce vídeo.
Para eso tengo el plugin de Easy Movie Texture, con el ejemplo de la esfera que me permite generar texturas de video en Android. Tome del ejemplo de Google Cardboard la cámara stereo, la introduje dentro de la esfera, y probé. Efectivamente obtengo un reproductor 360, peeero al mover la cabeza (y un poco también estando quieto) se siente como un lag o un barrido en el video, que dada la experiencia inmersiva puede generar un poco de mareo. Entonces la cuestion es esa, necesito solucionar el lag o retraso en el renderizado que tiene el video.
Las pruebas las estoy haciendo con Gear Vr y unos vr genericos, usando un Samsung S6 y un Motorola Moto G2, con ambos tengo el mismo efecto.
Si alguien tiene idea de a que se puede deber, desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Con que hardware estas reproduciendo el video?, puede ser por eso

Comment: Galaxy S6, Motorola Moto G2.

Comment: Como haces la prueba, generas el apk o lo trabajas remoto desde unity?

Comment: Probe tanto generando el apk como conectandolo con el modo de desarrollo habilitado para que Unity lance la app por adb. Hay algun camino mas eficiente, asi sea dejando de lado Unity, para desarrollar un reproductor de este tipo? Como dije, unicamente que pueda reproducir 360 y mover la camara segun el movimiento de los sensores usando gafas Vr...

Comment: Ok, creo que la textura que usas es muy pesada, puedes hacer la prueba reduciendo el tamaño del video por ejemplo 1080p -> 720p o 2160p -> 1080p, el Galaxy deberia poder reproducir sin lag

Comment: Sucede que el mismo video con la aplicacion de Oculus se reproduce bien, desconozco si Unity tiene configuraciones de calidad/rendimiento especificas para Vr

Comment: Te refieres al caso de Oculus o al emulador que hay para android?

Comment: Conecto el S6 a los GearVr, se abre el lobby de oculus, elijo Samsung Vr y reproduzco el video sin problemas...  Sin emulador, todo físico.